# Do ringneck parrots reject eggs of other parrots in their nest / eggs touched by humans?

Tags: ornithology

I've put up artificial parrot homes in my terrace. Parrots have been nesting there and have laid eggs in them. 
Of late i have been observing a large gathering of crows and a few hawks perching in the nearby trees, like never before,  presumably due to the large number of artificial nests and feeders that i've put up for sparrows and parrots.
I observed that in one of the parrot nests, the mother/father haven't returned for almost a week now, and i'm worried for the eggs.
1) If i transport them secretly to another nest, will the host couple accept them ?
2) Can parrots sense if humans touch their eggs ? Will they reject them?